# Animategraphics problem - invalid character

Tags: symbols, animate, gif

I wanted to include a GIF in my beamer tex file. I followed the instructions from https://www.baeldung.com/cs/latex-beamer-animations and converted the GIF file into multiple PNG files. Then I used the following micro example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\animategraphics[autoplay,loop,scale=0.4]{5}{easter-}{0}{2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this only produces the error

> "! Text line contains an invalid character. l.1 ^^@
> ^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@..."

Any idea what might cause this and how to fix it?

UPDATE: I changed the pictures and now the code is compiling, however the animation of the images does not work.

Comment: Please don't use comments for long codes, update your question instead.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I am not 100% sure, but I think, you cannot include a GIF using the `animate` package directly. You would have to generate PNGs for each frame of the GIF first. The frame title used in the linked example is misleading in my opinion. If you read the text, you will find that they actually don't include a GIF using this method.

Comment: Having said that, you might have converted the GIF to PNGs already. But even if you did, it is difficult to reproduce the error because you did not provide the file(s) you tried to embed. But I wonder whether this error is due to the graphics embedding anyways and not maybe rather due to some wrong setup of encodings or corrupted aux files.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already converted the GIF into PNG files (I updated the text above). 

How would I check or correct the setup of encoding or aux-files?